# Testing the blur event

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a counter component.

```
export const Counter: React.FC<CounterProps> = ({
  value,
  min = 0,
  max = 100,
  onChange,
  disabled
}) => {
  const [innerValue, setInnerValue] = useState(value);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (innerValue !== value) {
      setInnerValue(value);
    }
  }, [value]);

  min = Math.max(min, 0);

  const onValueChange: React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = event => {
    const newValue = Number(event.target.value);
    if (Number.isInteger(newValue) && newValue !== value) {
      setInnerValue(newValue);
    }
  };

  const onInputBlur = () => {
    const newValue = Math.min(Math.max(innerValue, min), max);
    if (newValue === value) {
      setInnerValue(newValue);
    } else {
      onChange(newValue);
    }
  };

  const increment = (delta: number) => {
    const newValue = value + delta;
    if (newValue >= min && newValue <= max) {
      onChange(value + delta);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <MinusButton
        onClick={() => increment(-1)}
        disabled={disabled || value <= min}
      >
        <IconMinusSvg />
      </MinusButton>
      <Input
        value={innerValue}
        onChange={onValueChange}
        disabled={disabled}
        onBlur={onInputBlur}
      />
      <PlusButton
        onClick={() => increment(1)}
        disabled={disabled || value >= max}
      >
        <IconPlusSvg />
      </PlusButton>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

the `onInputBlur()` function should take the value at the blur event and compare it with the minimum and maximum and set it to state. And if you enter the value 15 at a maximum of 10, after the blur event, the value 10 should get into the state. Everything works as it should in storybook.

But in the test I can't catch the value change:

```
test('enter a value', () => {
  const mockOnChange = jest.fn();
  render(<Counter value={5} onChange={mockOnChange} max={10} />);
  const input = document.querySelector('input') as HTMLElement;
  expect(input).toHaveValue('5');
  fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: 12 } });
  fireEvent.focusOut(input);
  expect(input).toHaveValue('10');
});
```

I also tried using `userEvent.tab()`

Test result:

```
enter a value
-----
Error: expect(element).toHaveValue(10)
Expected the element to have value:
  10
Received:
  12
```

How do I check that the `onInputBlur()` function is working correctly?